# When to create web service?

Tags: web-services, rest, web

I need help regarding web service that when should we use web service?
I know that it is used to give access to the web's functionalities to the other apps over the internet, even if it is a mobile app. But is it use to make a web service to use within a website, a big website or it is used for external use only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web Services were basically created to easily deal with firewalls on the web, since it uses the same http protocol.

So I'd say a Web Service is an interesting option when you need to expose some API for someone that will use your system on the web.

But of course, since many developers are familiar and since there are some nice tools, it's also an option for internal use too.

Answer (score 0):

Behind this, is a big theory and comes from a bigger topic called Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), which contains principles, definitions and a lot of theory contained in books.

Your question is too wide, however you can use web services (in a web context) to create an Application Programming Interface(API). The API can be used to:

1. Provide the backend to a front end application, this usually built in a JS framework. The backend is exposed via endpoints that collectively are known as web services.
2. Provide the backend to a mobile native application.
3. Or in general, provide a backend to any other system (embedded, desktop, etc).

This exposures are usually done with a protocol, (i.e REST) and usually a full documentation is provided to use the API. Also for security reasons the API probably restricts its endpoints with an authentication system.

Comment: @JunaidEffendi please select best solution.